# Node creation C

Tags: c, string, struct

so I am having weird problems trying to create a node with this struct:

```
struct node {
    char *value ;
    unsigned int count ;
    struct node *next ;
} ;
```

here's what i've got

```
struct node *make_node(char *value) {
    struct node *np = NULL;
    *np = (*np)malloc(sizeof(*np));
    char* copy = (char*)malloc(sizeof(strlen(value)+1));
    strcpy(copy, *value);
    *np -> *value = copy;
    *np -> count = 1;
    *np -> next = null; 
    return np ;
}
```

the string part is throwing me i think. I'm getting a bunch of incompatable pointer types.

--EDIT--
Answered, thank you all for helpin me

Comment: The language syntax violations in this alone warrant referencing you to [*any* decent **book on the C Programming Language**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The allocation line should read:

```
np = malloc(sizeof *np);
```

Note:

1. No asterisk before `np` on the left hand side, you don't want to dereference the pointer, you want to assign to it.
2. [No cast of `malloc()`'s return value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Then you must have:

```
np->value = copy;
```

Remember that `a->b` (for a `struct` pointer `a`) means `(*a).b`.

Finally, it's spelled `NULL`.

Assuming you have `strdup()`, your function can be written like this:

```
struct node * make_node(const char *value) {
    struct node *np = malloc(sizeof *np);
    if(np != NULL)
    {
        np->value = strdup(value);
        if(np->value != NULL)
        {
            np->count = 1;
            np->next = NULL;
            return np;
        }
        free(np);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
struct node *make_node(char *value) {
```

Your function does not modify `value`, so it is a good habit to declare it `const`.

```
struct node *make_node(char const *value) {
```

---

```
*np = (*np)malloc(sizeof(*np));
```

Don't dereference pointer on assignment. Also casting malloc is useless in C, and can hide bugs.

```
np = malloc(sizeof(*np));
```

Note that it is highly recommended that you check result of `malloc` for `NULL`. Memory allocation can fail.

---

```
char* copy = (char*)malloc(sizeof(strlen(value)+1));
```

You are correctly calculating size of string here `strlen(value)+1`, but after that the `sizeof` is incorrect. It will only return the size of `int`.

```
char* copy = malloc(strlen(value)+1);
```

---

```
strcpy(copy, *value);
```

`strcpy` takes `(char *, char const *)` not `(char *, char)`.

```
strcpy(copy, value);
```

---

```
*np -> *value = copy;
*np -> count = 1;
```

Again, dereferencing is not what you want. Only assign the pointer value (address).

```
np->value = copy;
np->count = 1;
```

---

```
*np -> next = null;
```

You probably meant `NULL` here.

```
np->next = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strcpy(copy, *value);
```

should be

```
strcpy(copy, value);
```

the `strcpy` function takes a char pointer as the second argument, source address.